# How to get current and last year's information

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following table. If there are no leads for a particular day, there will be no data entry.

```
Date        Center      Leads
1/1/2018    A           2
1/1/2018    B           1
1/2/2018    A           2
1/3/2018    A           4
1/3/2018    B           1
1/1/2019    A           3
1/3/2019    A           2
```

When I perform my join, I want to get this year and last year's leads by center. Additionally, if there are no leads this year but there is an entry for last year, I want to include this year in the result set as 0.

Result set:

```
Date        Center      Leads     Leads-PastYear
1/1/2018    A           2         0
1/1/2018    B           1         0
1/2/2018    A           2         0
1/3/2018    A           4         0
1/3/2018    B           1         0
1/1/2019    A           3         2
1/1/2019    B           0         1
1/2/2019    A           0         2
1/3/2019    A           2         4
1/3/2019    B           0         1
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
  T1.Date, 
  T1.Center, 
  T1.Leads, 
  T2.Leads AS 'Leads-PastYear' 
FROM table T1
LEFT JOIN table T2 ON 
  DATE_SUB(T1.Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) = T2.Date AND
  T1.Center = T2.Center

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
  DATE_ADD(T2.Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS 'Date', 
  T2.Center, 
  T1.Leads, 
  T2.Leads AS 'Leads-PastYear' 
FROM table T1
RIGHT JOIN table T2 ON 
  DATE_ADD(T2.DATE, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) = T1.Date AND
  T2.Center = T1.Center
WHERE DATE_ADD(T2.Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) NOT IN (SELECT T3.Date FROM table T3) AND 
YEAR(DATE_ADD(T2.Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) <= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: Expressing full join in MySQL is (obviously) a faq.

Comment: You result set is bit confusing `1/2/2018    A           0         2`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I edited the result set so now it's more clear

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of getting all the dates in the result set and then using `JOIN` to fetch the dates from the two years:

```
with dc as (
      select t.date, t.center
      from t
      where t.date >= datefromparts(year(getdate() - 1, 1, 1)
      union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select dateadd(year, 1, t.date), t.center
      from t
      where t.date >= datefromparts(year(getdate() - 1, 1, 1) and
            t.date < datefromparts(year(getdate(), 1, 1)
     )
select dc.date, dc.center, t.leads,
       coalesce(tprev.leads, 0) as prev_year_leads
from dc left join
     t
     on t.date = dates.date and t.center = dc.center left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.date = dateadd(year, -1, dates.date) and
        tprev.center = dc.center;
```

I am a bit wary of using window functions.  Leap years might cause problems.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! I really like that approach.  I found an alternate solution if you want to see my answer I'll post it below.

Comment: @WayneWong . . . I think your method might generate duplicate dates in the current year in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  T2.Date,
  T2.Center,
  SUM(T2.Leads),
  SUM(T2.Leads2)
FROM (
    SELECT 
      T1.Date AS Date,
      T1.Center AS Center,
      T1.Leads As Leads,
      0 AS Leads2
    FROM table T1

    UNION

    SELECT
      DATE_ADD(T1.Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS Date,
      T1.Center AS Center,
      0 AS Leads,
      T1.Leads AS Leads2
    FROM table T1
) AS T2

GROUP BY T2.Date, T2.Center
```